# Sorting a list of image filenames by number

Tags: python-3.x, sorting

I am trying to order the following list of image sequences. i.e. `frame0.jpg --> frame17.jpg`:

I have tried splitting the name, and then sorting them but it doesn't work.

Here's my code:

```
Data = [
    "D:\\shooting_videos\\example\\Output\\trained_framesmake2\\frame0.jpg",
    "D:\\shooting_videos\\example\\Output\\trained_framesmake2\\frame1.jpg",
    "D:\\shooting_videos\\example\\Output\\trained_framesmake2\\frame10.jpg",
    "D:\\shooting_videos\\example\\Output\\trained_framesmake2\\frame11.jpg",
    "D:\\shooting_videos\\example\\Output\\trained_framesmake2\\frame12.jpg",
    "D:\\shooting_videos\\example\\Output\\trained_framesmake2\\frame13.jpg",
    "D:\\shooting_videos\\example\\Output\\trained_framesmake2\\frame14.jpg",
    "D:\\shooting_videos\\example\\Output\\trained_framesmake2\\frame15.jpg",
    "D:\\shooting_videos\\example\\Output\\trained_framesmake2\\frame16.jpg",
    "D:\\shooting_videos\\example\\Output\\trained_framesmake2\\frame17.jpg",
    "D:\\shooting_videos\\example\\Output\\trained_framesmake2\\frame2.jpg",
    "D:\\shooting_videos\\example\\Output\\trained_framesmake2\\frame3.jpg",
    "D:\\shooting_videos\\example\\Output\\trained_framesmake2\\frame4.jpg",
    "D:\\shooting_videos\\example\\Output\\trained_framesmake2\\frame5.jpg",
    "D:\\shooting_videos\\example\\Output\\trained_framesmake2\\frame6.jpg",
    "D:\\shooting_videos\\example\\Output\\trained_framesmake2\\frame7.jpg",
    "D:\\shooting_videos\\example\\Output\\trained_framesmake2\\frame8.jpg",
    "D:\\shooting_videos\\example\\Output\\trained_framesmake2\\frame9.jpg",
]

sorted_Data = sorted(Data, key=lambda x: int(x.split('.')[0]))
```

Comment: Please [don't post images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question). Thanks.

Comment: `sorted_Data = sorted(x, key=lambda x: int(x.split('.')[0][5:]))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the regex `(\d+)\.[a-z]+$`, which captures digits immediately before the file name extension, which is assumed to be alphabetical.

```
import re

sorted(data, key=lambda x: int(re.search(r"(\d+)\.[a-z]+$", x).group(1)))
```